# Untouched code suddenly throws Method not found: 'Void Swashbuckle.Application.SwaggerDocsConfig.RootUrl' on startup

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, swashbuckle

I just opened an application of which I need it's API to create the necessary data required for the application I'm actually working on.

On startup of the API I get this error:

```
System.MissingMethodException
  HResult=0x80131513
  Message=Method not found: 'Void Swashbuckle.Application.SwaggerDocsConfig.RootUrl(System.Func`2<System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage,System.String>)'.
  Source=Scanner.Api
  StackTrace:
   at Scanner.Api.Configuration.SwaggerConfiguration.<>c.<ConfigureApiDocumentation>b__0_0(SwaggerDocsConfig c) in C:\MyApplication.Api\Configuration\SwaggerConfiguration.cs:line 176
   at Swashbuckle.Application.HttpConfigurationExtensions.EnableSwagger(HttpConfiguration httpConfig, String routeTemplate, Action`1 configure)
   at Scanner.Api.Configuration.SwaggerConfiguration.ConfigureApiDocumentation(HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration) in C:\MyApplication.Api\Configuration\SwaggerConfiguration.cs:line 13
   at Scanner.Api.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app, IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions identityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions) in C:\MyApplication.Api\Startup.cs:line 61
```

The only thing that's changed is that my laptop has had a full Windows reinstall.

The code itself was cloned and no changes.

The SwaggerConfiguration mentioned above:

```
public static class SwaggerConfiguration
{
    public static HttpConfiguration ConfigureApiDocumentation(this HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration)
    {
        httpConfiguration
            .EnableSwagger("docs/{apiVersion}/swagger", c =>
            {
                c.RootUrl(RootUrlResolver);
                c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Scanner.Api");
                var xmlCommentsFile = XmlCommentsFilePath();
                if (File.Exists(xmlCommentsFile))
                    c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlCommentsFile);

                c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
            })
            .EnableSwaggerUi("docs/{*assetPath}", c =>
            {
                c.DisableValidator();
            });
        return httpConfiguration;
    }

    private static string XmlCommentsFilePath()
    {
        var xmlCommentsPath = $"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\\bin\\Scanner.Api.xml";
        return xmlCommentsPath;
    }


    private static string RootUrlResolver(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var rootUrl = $"{request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)}{request.GetRequestContext().VirtualPathRoot.TrimEnd('/')}";
        return rootUrl;
    }
}
```

> What could cause this and what's the solution?

**Update**

I did an update-package to force every package to the latest version, followed by a delete of all `bin` and `obj` folders in the entire solution structure. Didn't fix the issue.

Comment: It sounds like a compilation issue. It usually happens because you compile a classy-library project but the starting project which references that library has a different version of the assembly in its bin folder. Not always a clean/rebuild works, the best thing to do is to delete folders 'bin' and 'obj' for all projects and rebuild

Comment: @Phate01: See update

Comment: I just realized that the method not found is on a nuget package, it seems like that your library has a different version of the package Swashbuckle than the starter project

Comment: @Spikee did you ever solve this issue?  If so can you post the answer?

Comment: @Abr: The below answer is pretty much what I did (check package versions, clean up bin/obj, ...). Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @Spikee thanks - I actually ended up having to do a binding redirect on System.Net.Http to fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to recompile all your code and ensure that all the .dll files are the correct ones into the "bin" directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check the dependentAssemblies in the runtime section in your Web.config. There were some that were missing on the server and when I copied the ones from my local Web.config it resolved this error.